# Invoking arbitrary Actions with nUnits test runner

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates, nunit

I'm trying to customize some of nUnits behaviour, however I'm constantly hitting a brick wall
because of nUnits heavy use of code reflection. Test methods (and also setup methods etc) are passed all the way down, deep into the framework, and are converted into a delegate at the latest step possible.

The classes I'm interested in are called TestCommands and only there the framework becomes functional.

For reference here is a snippet I found in nUnits source of the TestMethodCommand class which propably is the bread and butter test execution delegate.

```
public class TestMethodCommand : TestCommand
{
    private readonly TestMethod testMethod;
    private readonly object[] arguments;

    public TestMethodCommand(TestMethod testMethod) : base(testMethod)
    {
        this.testMethod = testMethod;
        this.arguments = testMethod.Arguments;
    }

    public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    {
        object result = InvokeTestMethod(context); // missing a branch deciding about sync vs. async

        // missing some code that checks object against "expected result"

        return context.CurrentResult;
    }

    private object InvokeTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
    {
        return testMethod.Method.Invoke(context.TestObject, arguments);
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled why nUnit couldn't wrap the test method into an `Func<object>` way way sooner and just pass the context along. As it stands for now if I don't have a MethodInfo nUnit can't run it.

In case you wonder, here is an example of a thing I want to do but I ran into the same problem in other instances as well.

```
[Scenario(When: "Device Registration reads out PCB Type",
          Then: "Device Type might change")]
public void Identifier_Changes_Are_Recognized()
{
    var changedType = reference.ChangeType(DeviceType.Terminal);
    var changedID = reference.ChangeID(123456);

    Assert.Multiple(() => 
    {
        AssertIsSameDevice(reference, changedType);
        AssertIsDifferentDevice(reference, changedID);
    });
}
```

This scenario attribute is supposed to print a small description like so.

```
public void RunBeforeTest()
{
    var text = new MultiLineText
        ("Scenario:",
            "\tGiven:\t" + When,
            "\tThen:\t" + Then,
            "-------------\n"
        );

    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

I reaaallly want to tell nUnit "Look, here is an action, please run it" but for the time beeing this seems very hard to achieve. Did anyone else here run in these kinds of problems?
Are there possibly ways to achieve what I'm trying to do? Maybe create my own TestCommand, but as I mentioned, these objects only get created very deep into the framework.

Comment: I see you have  found a solution for yourself, but I just thought I'd point out that NUnit is a pretty mature product and targets (or  targeted in the past) platforms where generics didn't exist. :-) So that's why it couldn't do it. A new rewrite, of course, could.

Answer (score 0):

OP here (Writing from my home account)

I looked more into this and actually found a working solution:

```
    public class ArbitraryCodeExecutionWrapper : DelegatingTestCommand
    {
        public ArbitraryCodeExecutionWrapper(TestCommand innerCommand) : base(innerCommand)
        {
        }

        public Action<TestExecutionContext> BeforeTest { get; init; } = _ => { };
        public Action<Test, TestResult> AfterTest { get; init; } = (_,_) => { };

        public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
        {
            BeforeTest(context);
            var result = innerCommand.Execute(context);
            AfterTest(context.CurrentTest, result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class NUnitTestCommandWrapperAttribute : Attribute, IWrapTestMethod
    {
        protected virtual void BeforeTest(TestExecutionContext context)
        {
        }
        protected virtual void AfterTest(Test test, TestResult result)
        {
        }

        public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
            => new ArbitraryCodeExecutionWrapper(command)
            {
                BeforeTest = BeforeTest,
                AfterTest = AfterTest
            };

    }

    public class ScenarioAttribute : NUnitTestCommandWrapperAttribute
    {
        public string When { get; init; } = "";
        public string Then { get; init; } = "";

        protected override void BeforeTest(TestExecutionContext context)
        {
            var text = new MultiLineText
                ("Scenario:",
                    "\tGiven:\t" + When,
                    "\tThen:\t" + Then
                );
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        protected override void AfterTest(Test test, TestResult result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("After Test");
        }

    }


    [TestFixture]
    public class TestCodeExecution
    {
        [Test]
        [Scenario(When = "nUnit Comes here",
                  Then = "Print Hello World")]
        public void Try_Out_Code_Execution()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");        
        }
    }

    public class MultiLineText
    {
        private List<string> items = new();
        public static implicit operator string(MultiLineText text) => text.ToString();

        public MultiLineText(params string[] lines)
        {
            items = lines.ToList();
        }
        public override string ToString() => string.Join("\n", items);
    }
```